# Symfony 2.8 Avoiding double error from Callback

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

In my entity I have the following attribute:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="programm", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1M",
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Es sind nur pdf, jpg und png Dateien erlaubt",
 *     groups={"new"}
 * )
 */
private $programm;
```

and a Callback

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validateFields(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
    if ('' == $this->programm && 2 == $this->programmextern) {
        $context->buildViolation('Bitte Datei hochladen')->atPath('programm')->addViolation();
    }
```

If the Assert\File gives an error (file too big, file doesn't have the proper mimeType, etc) I want to skip the Callback. Is there a way to access the errors produced by Assert\File in my entity, so I can trigger my Callback only if there aren't any errors?

If not, is there a way to filter errors so that, if there is more than one error, only the AssertFile error is displayed in the twig template?

Answer (score 0):

Then most simple option comes in mind to achieve what you want is to add a different validation group to the callback:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(
 *     groups={"trigger_after_new"}
 * )
 */
public function validateFields(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
    if ('' == $this->programm && 2 == $this->programmextern) {
        $context->buildViolation('Bitte Datei hochladen')->atPath('programm')->addViolation();
}
```

and then read [How to Sequentially Apply Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html) to trigger the callback only if previous validator groups passed with success.